# Extending text selection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

If a user selects a portion of text, I'd like to extend that selection to the beginning of the first line and to the end of the last line if they select in the middle.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you working inside an editable region like textarea?

Comment: Do you mean a selection within a `<textarea>` or within regular content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setSelectionRange(beg, end) or selectionStart/selectionEnd to change the selection.
Basically from current selection range, you try to get the index (start, end) of the span indices you're trying to select and then change the selection.
Assuming you want to wrap/extend the selection to nearest "NEWLINE"s, here's a sample code:

`var x = $("#input input:first")[0];
var value = x.value;
var NEWLINE = '\n'; // whatever is your newline delimiter.
var start = value.substr(0, x.selectionStart).lastIndexOf(NEWLINE);
if (start == -1) start = 0;
var end = value.substr(x.selectionEnd).indexOf(NEWLINE);
if (end == -1) end = value.length;`

x.setSelectionRange(start, end);
or
x.selectionStart = start, x.selectionEnd = end;